# understanding NSString Allocation

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

```
[myDictionary objectForKey:kYourKey];
```

is returning `NSString` Object, but following code:

```
if (![[myDictionary objectForKey:kYourKey] isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
{
   //Conditional Code.
}
```

throws me out of the App. However the following works pretty fine :

```
NSString *tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:kYourKey]];
if (![tempStr isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
{
    //Conditional Code.
}
```

What is the difference, here?

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference. What do you mean by "throws me out of the App"? What is the exception/error message?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ae9cd8'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
po [myDictionary objectForKey:kYourKey]
```

in the debugger, or

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([[myDictionary objectForKey:kYourKey] class]);
```

My guess is that the object is *not* an `NSString`, but an `NSNull`.

Edit: yep. I missed your last comment. It is indeed `NSNull`.

Comment: Yes, It's NSNull object., btw, what is po [myDictionary objectForKey:kYourKey] ? I don't know.

Comment: @Krishna po is "print object", a GDB command which invokes `debugDescription` method defined in `NSObject` since, I believe, NeXTstep days. It is also supported in LLDB.

Comment: Wait, wait... I don't know that much. Again one Question arises. what is GDB Command? Rather, Can you point me to some documentation for that? I am also interested in learning command line use of Xcode.

Comment: @Krishna GDB and LLDB are debuggers used by Xcode. A debugger is a programmer tool allowing to step through the code, peak at applications' memory, control the code flow from outside, and about 4096 other useful things. Using a debugger is a huge topic and an art in itself. I recommend WWDC 2011 session videos for a good introduction to using a debugger in Xcode.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely see it.

Answer (score 3):

A string is not actually being returned, by using stringWithFormat you converted the null into the string `@"<null>"`. This test would probably be more appropriate,

```
id testObject = [myDictionary objectForKey:kYourKey];
if(testObject != nil && ![testObject isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
//Conditional Code
}
```

**EDIT**

Also [NSNull null] is a singleton so you can convert the above test into a more compact test.

```
id testObject = [myDictionary objectForKey:kYourKey];
if(testObject == [NSNull null]){
    //Conditional Code
}
```

Comment: Testing for NSNull can safely be done by pointer comparison `testObject == [NSNull null]`. NSNull is a singleton.

Answer (score -2):

Type-Casting

```
if(![((NSString*)[myDictionary objectForKey:kYourKey]) isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
```

Comment: Tried it... Same result. uncaught exception.